# ZFS on Linux "no such device in pool"

Tags: 14.04, zfs

I have a pool which contains a disc with only a few errors.  I wanted to clear those errors out and see if they came back before I purchased a new disc:

```
me@server:/$ sudo zpool status tank
  pool: tank
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices are faulted in response to persistent errors.
        Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue functioning in a
        degraded state.
action: Replace the faulted device, or use 'zpool clear' to mark the device
        repaired.
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 7h1m with 0 errors on Sat May 24 20:44:13 2014
config:

        NAME                                            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        tank                                            DEGRADED     0     0     0
          raidz2-0                                      DEGRADED     0     0     0
            ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F1HTEW             ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F1HDXJ             ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F1J33Y             FAULTED      9     1     0  too many errors
            ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F1HM7F             ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F1HE23             ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F175HQ             ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F1K3TV             ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F1D1XR             ONLINE       0     0     0
        logs
          ata-SSD2SC120GS4DH08B-T_PNY10130000139160634  ONLINE       0     0     0
        cache
          ata-SSD2SC120GS4DH08B-T_PNY10130000139160672  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

I offlined the disc in question using its `guid` obtained from the `zdb` command:

```
zpool offline tank 12956315685006632708
```

I cleared the errors:

```
zpool clear tank 12956315685006632708
```

Then I tried to online the disc, but was greeted with the following:

```
zpool online tank 12956315685006632708
cannot online 12956315685006632708: no such device in pool
```

I have tried substituting the GUID with `ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F1J33Y` and with `/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F1J33Y` but I get the same results.

I also tried using the `replace` command with all the above identifiers with no luck.

I have read about a `cfgadm` command that I may need to run to "unconfigure/reconfigure" the disc, but it does not appear to be available to Ubuntu.

**How do I get this disc back online?**

Answer (score 2):

With help from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/305830/replacing-a-dead-disk-in-a-zpool) and its answers I was able to get this working (currently resilvering).  To any ZFS developers reading this, the operation of replacing a disc should be made much easier/full (and fool) proof.  After the initial setup and on a long enough time line the only operation every ZFS user will eventually have to do is replace a disc.  But I digress.

In my case I didn't want to replace my drive, I only wanted to clear its faults and get it back online fault free so I could determine if the disc actually needed to be replaced.  My reasoning for wanting to do this was 1.) the system had been on for nearly a year without a reboot so bit rot is a possibility 2.) the number of errors was fairly small.

The trick it seemed for me was to delete the partitions from the disc in question.  First I needed to determine which device to operate on.  You could determine this via process of elimination using `zdb`, but I used `lshw` to get all the info I needed at once.  Basically I wanted to correlate the the device `zpool status` was telling me had failed to a `/dev/sdX` device (if you are not familiar with `less` just use the up/down keys to show more/less and the `q` key to quit).

```
root@server:/# lshw|less
...
              *-disk:2
                   description: ATA Disk
                   product: ST3000DM001-1CH1
                   vendor: Seagate
                   physical id: 0.2.0
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.2.0
                   logical name: /dev/sdd
                   version: CC24
                   serial: Z1F1J33Y
                   size: 2794GiB (3TB)
                   capacity: 2794GiB (3TB)
                   capabilities: 15000rpm gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                   configuration: ansiversion=6 guid=52d25a12-120a-1c40-92a1-0be436c2d642 sectorsize=4096
                 *-volume:0
                      description: OS X ZFS partition or Solaris /usr partition
                      vendor: Solaris
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: scsi@0:0.2.0,1
                      logical name: /dev/sdd1
                      serial: f25724a4-dd55-764c-af34-9479521854b9
                      capacity: 2794GiB
                      configuration: name=zfs
                 *-volume:1
                      description: reserved partition
                      vendor: Solaris
                      physical id: 9
                      bus info: scsi@0:0.2.0,9
                      logical name: /dev/sdd9
                      serial: 89eeeedb-e3a0-4940-8a50-d3d7506ad603
                      capacity: 8191KiB
...
```

Here I can see that `/dev/sdd` is the disc I wanted.  I then deleted the partitions from that disc:

```
root@server:/# fdisk -l /dev/sdd
```

Then just follow the onscreen prompts for deleting the partition.  [Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-how-to-delete-a-partition-with-fdisk-command/) is a good guide.  After that the following command finally worked:

```
root@server:/# zpool replace tank 12956315685006632708 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F1J33Y
```

The `guid` (that long number) was obtained using the `zdb` command.  I *think* in the end I might have been able to use the `online` command instead of `replace`, but I didn't try that.

Comment: zpool status -g :   Display vdev GUIDs instead of the normal device names.

This will show the GUIDs that you need to run your replace commands.